# Phonegap Build for Windows Phone avoid rejection

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I've used Phonegap and Phonegap build.

I had got back some edits from Microsoft that my application closes when you navigate away and reopens when you navigate back to it.

I was using Phonegap build with version 2.0, and 2.2.

Should I consider upgrading to version 2.7.0 and maybe it will resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the most Win 7/8 mobile supported version of Phonegap is 2.7.0. 
Remember you have to also allow for back-button usage on win8
http://www.risingj.com/archives/493